# Youth finds ring in a graveyard and uses it to travel back and forth between the past and present

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, young-adult

edit - Thank you, community. Someone had the right book, I really cannot that you all enough!

This has been bothering me for years and I never finished reading the book. When I was younger (around 1994-1996) I read a young adult book about a youth who finds a ring in graveyard. They put on the ring and spin it causing them to go back in time (if I remember correctly the youth only goes back to the 1880s). When staying in the graveyard they are a solid person, when they leave the graveyard they become like a ghost. This person falls in love with another youth they meet in the past. They travel back and forth often between the present and the past.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Is the person they meet in the past also ghost-like or a real living person?  Is there any aspect of changing (or trying to change) history?

Comment: Was the youth a girl? (Elizabeth, maybe?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This sounds very similar to the plot of *[Your time, my time](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/10779092-your-time-my-time)*, a book by Ann Walsh, first published in 1984.

Set in a remote Canadian community in British Columbia, it tells the story of Elizabeth Connell who finds a magic ring in a cemetery that allows her to travel in time.

From a review on Goodreads:

> After much exploring of the township and its surroundings, she
> discovers the old cemetery and soon finds a peaceful spot that becomes
> her place to read and write and daydream and doze. It is in the
> graveyard that she one day uncovers a small gold ring, a ring with
> some rather inexplicable powers.
>
> Twisting the ring on her finger, she is transported back to the 19th
> century, to Barkerville’s gold rush heyday. And it is there – in the
> rather new cemetery of 1870 – that she meets a freckled boy with a
> crooked nose, a curious nature and a loving heart, who swiftly
> captures her own heart.

The boy is named Steve, and they fall in love. She indeed finds that she cannot travel outside the graveyard when she is in the past:

> she and Steve learn that she cannot travel outside of the cemetery
> into Barkerville of 1870, and she can take no one with her on these
> travels. There are boundaries to this time travel.

Comment: Thank you, Thank you Thank you!!! This is the book. Now to find it so I can finish reading it after all these years :)